# The simplest discrete periodic correlation function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

In probability theory there are several "basic" distributions like normal, uniform, Cauchy, etc. Due to CLT the first distribution one would consider to describe something is normal distribution.

What about discrete 1D autocorrelation functions? What is the first discrete autorerrelation function to consider? Something like $\exp\{-a |k|\}$? If so, what is the simplest *periodic* autocorrelation function?

Comment: I think the first and the simplest autocorrelation function to consider is the autocorrelation function of iid random variables.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Which is delta-function? OK, what if there *is* some correlation. (P.S. I clarified the question: I am interested in discrete autocorrelation functions)